# Reducing current for 5x5 IR transmitter matrix

Tags: current-limiting, high-current

I'm currently working on a project that involves a 25 IR transmitter matrix, with each individual IR transmitter requiring around 50mA of current. This results in a total current requirement of approximately 1.25A for the entire matrix.

Initially, I tried using a parallel connection for all single IR transmitters, which worked fine for providing the required 1.25A current. However, I soon realized that the Arduino can only handle a maximum of 40mA current output, making this solution unsuitable.

To address this issue, I thought of using a 5V 2A AC-DC adapter, which can efficiently handle the current demands of the entire matrix. However, the problem arises with the breadboard I'm currently using for prototyping. The standard breadboard can't handle current greater than 1A, making it unsuitable for my project's requirements.

Unfortunately, I'm not proficient in soldering, which makes custom PCBs a challenging option for me. Moreover, I want to avoid using soldering to simplify the setup and make it easier to manage.

I'm seeking advice and suggestions on how to manage the high current demands of the 5x5 IR transmitter matrix without resorting to custom PCBs or soldering. Additionally, I'm interested in any recommendations for breadboard power supply modules or alternative solutions that can handle the 1.25A current safely.

Your help and guidance in finding a suitable solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An IR LED needs current limiting. If you connect it directly to 5V then it will blow up. If you connect some LEDs in parallel they will all conduct a different amount of current and have different brightnesses.

Comment: Can you show a circuit diagram? It isn't clear what you have done. But assuming this is an array of LEDs, you set the current to whatever you want with resistors. If it's an integrated chip, the datasheet may have more information.

Comment: So i connected the transmitter in a array in which i shared them with a common ground and connected the transmitter positive end in a parallel connection so each sub branch draws a current of 50ma results in 1.25A. 
Sorry i didn't have the circuit diagram as I am very new in this field... The transmitter i am using is 5mm transmitter with forward voltage of 1.2V and 50ma current.@user1850479
I also tried like adding a 220 ohm resistance at the main branch so that the voltage get drops and my IR transmitter don't blow up @Audioguru

Comment: the description belongs in the question ... this site is not a forum ... please do not use comments to add information

Comment: why are you using an array? ... are you controlling the LEDs individually?

Comment: @jsotola No  , i am not controlling them individually . I connected them I parallel so that each transmitter can get 5v supply and then shared a common ground.
My basic purpose is to turn ON these 25 transmitters at the same time .Please Suggest if there is better some approach for same.

Comment: common power and common ground is not a 5x5 matrix ... it is just 25 LEDs connected in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a 5 V supply and the diodes have a forward voltage of 1.2 V it is not a good solution to connect all 25 diodes in parallel for several reasons:

1. The total power consumption of the LEDs is 1.2 V x 1.25 A = 1.5 W. You need a resistor in series with the LEDs, that defines the current. Across this resistor you have the voltage difference of 3.8 V, the resistance would be 3.8 V / 1.25 A = ~3 ohm. This resistor would dissipate 4.75 W, which is more than three times the power of the LEDs. The power dissipation stays the same if you conect the LEDs individually with a series resistor of 76 ohm for each LED.
2. There are small tolerances in the forward voltage and the LEDs with lower voltage would receive a higher current. The negative temperature coefficient of a typical IR LED will lower the forward voltage even more.
3. Your power supply must deliver 6.25 W and if you later want to control the LEDs with a MOSFET you have to switch the full 1.25 A.

If you split the LEDs into 8 groups of 3 LEDs connected in series, the situation is much better. The one LED left to 25 will have a resistor of its own:

1. In such a group the LED voltages add to 3.6 V and 1.4 V remains for the resistor. The total LED power again is 1.5 W, but the resistors dissipate only 8 x 1.4 V x 50 mA + 1 x 3.8 V x 50 mA = 0.56 W + 0.19 W = 0.75 W.
2. The needed current from the supply is only 9 x 50 mA = 450 mA, the needed power is just 2.25 W (still not qualified for a green label award).

This schematic shows 2 of the 8 groups as example and the single LED.
The IR LED used in the simulator (QED123) has a different forward voltage and so the simulated currents do not match your LED data.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzyQ95.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

An alternative would be 6 groups of 4 LEDs in series (4.8 V) and only 0.2 V across the resistors of 4 ohm each. This option offers low power waste, but small supply voltage variations have a big impact on the LED current.
The total resistor power dissipation would be 0.25 W.